# Is it OK to submit the sitemap file to Google without pointing one in the Webmaster Tools?

Tags: google, google-search-console, sitemap

I'd like to create several sitemaps and gather them into one sitemap index. Then I'd like to submit the sitemap index to Google (and other SE's) using [those](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemap_index#Submitting_Sitemaps) links. From my point of view it should be enough to be well indexed, but I'd like to be sure that it is not necessary to point the sitemap index to Google's Webmaster Tools.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use GWT to make Google aware of an XML sitemap. It's just one of the ways they make available to webmasters but isn't the only way or a required way. You can use [robots.txt](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183669?hl=en) to accomplish this as well.

Comment: Thanks - it's clear. But I'd like to ping Google pretty often for the new pages on the site so I thought that submitting sitemap index will be a good idea. Right?

Comment: Sure. But Google seems to crawl them at their own pre-determined schedule so pinging them doesn't seem to accomplish much in terms of increasing their crawl rate of the XML sitemaps. But as long as you keep the sitemaps up to date they're gonna find that content which is what matters.

Comment: On a recent site (about 150+ pages) I decided to test the robots.txt method. With just a `Sitemap:` entry in robots.txt and without submitting the sitemap to GWT or pinging it, Googlebot appears to be requesting the sitemap.xml file every 4 or 5 days. In GWT, Crawl > Blocked URLs > "robots.txt analysis", it reports "Valid Sitemap reference detected". However, under Crawl > Sitemaps it states "No sitemaps found for this site". So, _assuming_ that Googlebot is using the sitemap file when requested, it still seems necessary to actually submit a sitemap in GWT in order to get a _sitemap report_.

Comment: the important part @w3d is, are the pages being crawled? because if you see a mismatch on the result about the sitemap itself, but the pages are indexed, that just means that the two parts of the code on the GWT are not connected and one doesn't update the other, but no serious consequences for you, the user.

Comment: @PatomaS: All the pages would seem to have been crawled and indexed, but whether this is because of the XML sitemap I don't know. The pages are all abundantly internally linked, so the need for an XML sitemap is admittedly low in my case.

Comment: I see. Most probably similar experiences would be shared, since the only way to know for sure would be to have somebody from Google answering that or making a true experiment, and even that would be difficult because of all the variables involved.